# Cast a dropdown list from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, casting

I am attempting to use a findcontrol method to dynamically fill a drop down list.  I keep getting a null reference and have tried a couple different ways.  Here is some code that Ive tried.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
           ID="ddlCalculateGrid" 
           Style="border: none; border-width: 0px; width: 90%"
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCalculateGrid_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
           AutoPostBack="true">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" 
           ID="hdnCalculate" 
           Value='<%# Eval("Calculate") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

and here is the back end code.

```
        DropDownList tempddl;
        tempddl = (DropDownList)grvbillDetail.FindControl("ddlCalculateGrid");
        tempddl.DataSource = rcta.GetDataByTrueValue();
        tempddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: Do you have any other control on top of the GridView. I mean is this a nested gridview?

Comment: Where exactly is this backend code? on some gridview event handler? Also note that the controls defined in the GridView template do not directly belong to the gridview; they belong the `GridViewRow`. So you might want to loop thru `grvbillDetail.Rows` and then try doing a `FindControl()` on each row.

Comment: Have you verified that FindControl() returns something?  What is rcta and are you sure it is not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dropdown is in an item template. This means your gridview could contain several drop downs (one in each row) or none at all if the gridview is bound to a source with no rows.

If you're looking to bind each dropdown for each row, you would do so in the GridViewRowDatabound event like so.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grvbillDetail.RowDataBound += grvbillDetail_RowDataBound;
}

void grvbillDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        return;
    var ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlCalculateGrid") as DropDownList;
    if (ddl != null)
    {
        ddl.DataSource = rcta.GetDataByTrueValue();
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is in an item template, the easiest thing would be to use a handler on the dropdownlist itself:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCalculateGrid" 
    Style="border: none; border-width: 0px;width: 90%"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCalculateGrid_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
    OnLoad="ddlCalculateGrid_OnLoad"
    AutoPostBack="true">
```

and then in the ddlCalculateGrid_OnLoad method:

```
DropDownList tempddl = (DropDownList)sender;
```

Answer (score 1):

since this is a row in a gridview there can be many instances of this dropdownlist. you have to loop through each row in your gridview

```
foreach (GridViewRow tt in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (tt.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {                    
              tt.FindControl("ddlCalculateGrid");
            }
        }
```